# How can I store table data in SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework, store

At this moment I am building an app in ionic platform, the data is being stored in SQLite local storage. But I need to know how I can store this data into SQL Server database?

Answer (score 1):

It is unsecure to connect to a real database server directly from your phone. The connection string can be exposed and the data changed/stolen/deleted.

What you need is a back end like asp.net/node.js/ruby or whatever your choice should be.

This server should act as the bridge between your app and the database. Receiving json from http requests and storing it in the database.

Comment: Thank you @misha130 , Is there any Tutorial or documentation available regarding this ??

Comment: Well I guess since you know javascript you can do a node.js server. You should ask for consultance if you can before you start. Here is a link http://blog.modulus.io/build-your-first-http-server-in-nodejs